# Introductory book on (only) Topological Manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation

In all of the recommendation posts on an introduction to manifolds, the books suggested primarily focus on smooth manifolds, such as Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* and Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds*.

Are there any books which deal *only* with topological manifolds, and not bring smooth structure into the picture at all? Till now, the only one I've found it is Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*. Are there other such books?

Comment: What are you precisely looking for? Lee's book is a great source. Maybe you want to have a look at the term ''algebraic topology''. So search for titles like: An introduction to Algebraic topology. Does this help?

Comment: Algebraic topology talks about the interplay between algebra and topology in general, though. It doesn't talk about topological manifolds at all. 

Also, I agree that Lee's book is a great source. I just like having an alternative resource to look at, if I ever need to. Which is why I was asking about other books which deal with only topological manifolds. Does this make it a bit clearer for you?

Comment: One issue is that many of the tools used to study topological manifolds (homotopy groups, (co)homology, combinatorial decompositions, etc.) also apply to a wider variety of topological spaces, and so most texts that cover them tend to do so in full generality. In this sense, many algebraic topology texts (e.g. Hatcher) *do* deal with topological manifolds, but not always by name, instead referring to locally compact Hausdorff spaces, CW complexes, and so on.

Comment: Note that J. Lee wrote more than one book, and one of these, *Introduction to topological manifolds*, may be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: The Lee book is just a first-semester general topology book, but with exercises on manifolds and the classification of compact surfaces.  The issue is that as soon as you get to dim 4 you need smooth and algebraic techniques.  Moise's "Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3" is probably your best bet for getting somewhat deep without already needing to know smooth/PL/algebraic stuff.  You could also go through the complete classification of surfaces; it's approachable.  Rushing's "Topological Embeddings" is approachable after Hatcher, it's the next step.  Then Daverman's "Decompositions of Manifolds."